# Why dont I get an output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a test file to use to get the output but I dont get the output instead I get a syntax error. I am new to python. Please help.

The required output is:

```
remove_value Test

  ['r', 'i', 'g']    
  ['i', 'n', 'g']
  ['r', 'i', 'n']
```

my code is:

```
def remove_value (my_list, remove_position): 
    new_list = []
    for i in my_list:
        if str(i) != str(value):
            new_list.append(i)
        count = count+1
    return new_list
```

Test file in which the output is in:

```
print("\nremove_value Test")

str_list5 = ['r','i','n','g']
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, 2)
print(new_list)
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, -1)
print(new_list)
new_list = list_function.remove_value(str_list5, 10)
print(new_list)

print("\nremove_value Test")
num_list3 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
num_list3 = list_function.remove_value(num_list3, 1)
print(num_list3)
```

Comment: call the function

Comment: How? I am new sorry. Could you write that part up. I have spent last three hours on this.

Comment: at the end of file type `remove_value(yourlist,remove_position)` but you didn't use `remove_position` and  where is `value`

Comment: `value` is not defined, I think? And you don't need `count` when you use a for-loop. Further, the intendation is incorrect: Since Python relies heavily on indentation, you should indent everything below the definition of the function and then, as Hisham wrote, call the function.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code (and get rid of those blank lines). Your code doesn't define `value`, and  `remove_value` doesn't use the `remove_position` argument. You need to call the `remove_value` function with appropriate arguments, capture the list it returns, and print it.

Comment: Hi sorry could you edit my code above i'm having trouble understandind.

Comment: @peterwes Tell us what are you trying to accomplish in the remove_value method?

Comment: DavidG has edited your code, but please check it to make sure it's correct. I suspect that you want the `count = count+1` line to be part of the `if` block. If so, it needs to be indented one more level.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes you're probably right, I didn't spot that.

Comment: I'm now getting this error. Sorry I dont understand this program. NameError: name 'value' is not defined

Comment: I assume you want to input a list and a value into your `remove_value` function, the output of which returns a new list with all the occurances of `value` removed?

Comment: Yes. But my skillset in this language is limited so I have no idea where to go to next.

Comment: Please consider working through a decent [Python tutorial](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Comment: @DavidG We generally avoid fixing indentation errors in OP's code because the bad indentation may be the cause of (or part of) their problem, so it's better to try to help the OP do it for themself.

Comment: There is no indentation problem. It only was looking that way due to me having to copy it from idle.  Could someone please help with the issue. I think there is something I am ment to put near or above count = count+1

Comment: There has been some confusion in regards to what the ouput should be. I have pasted the testfile functions aboves. Please help.

Comment: @peterwes please tell me - do you understand what your own code means, like what each line does? If not you are in the wrong place to seek help, you should be looking at tutorials that explain how certain constructs operate or running a syntactically valid but otherwise broken code through [pythontutor.com](pythontutor.com).  Please come back when you understand each statement individually and still don't understand the output it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also try it this way

```
def remove_val(my_list,val):
    return [x for x in my_list if x!=val]



print (remove_val([1,2,3,4,3,3], 3))
```

gives the output

```
[1, 2, 4]
```